# No SystemPropertyColumns in Azure Stream Analytics from visual studio 2019(v: 16.3.9)

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2019, azure-stream-analytics

Not able to see System Property Columns as we have in azure portal in visual studio 2019. Below is the screen shot for output configuration of Service bus queue.

[image]

Below is the screenshot of system property column in azure portal
[image]

Problem is the ARm template generated from project won't have system property columns. 
Anyone faced such issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature of ASA output in VS 2019 is equal to everyone i think.My tool version is `16.4.2`.

[image]

I tried to create the system property columns on the portal and view the json structure in the https://resources.azure.com/.

[image]

I tried to find some [official evidence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/david/building-azure-stream-analytics-resources-via-arm-templates-part-2-the-template) but nothing related could be found. Especially for this :
[image]

You could try to `edit` your output.json file to add the key-value manually.If it's still block,then it seems that the feature is not supported in ARM so far.

[image]

Comment: i have tried adding the systempropertycolumns to output already, but it does not work. It does not add it in ARM template generated.

Comment: @Rusty Fine.It seems that it's not supported yet.Surely,you could contact ASA team to verify this.

Comment: @Rusty Hey,Rusty. Please refer to below comment to follow the progress of your concern.

Answer (score 2):

<del>System Property Column is not supported on Visual Studio at this moment.</del>

== Update: System Property Columns are now supported. Please update the ASA extension to try this feature.

Comment: Cool,appreciated for any evidences or some statements of extension.

Comment: Thank you, Jay. Your answer is awesome. I'm a developer of the ASA VS extension, and we have a plan to support this feature asap.

Comment: It's big appreciated for your confirmation.

Comment: this is supported in visual studio now, but in CICD nuget package it is still not supported i think, because when i deploy using 2.3.0.0 nuget package it does not work
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.StreamAnalytics.CICD/

Comment: Hi @Rusty, thank you so much for your support. We are still polishing the CICD tool, and I believe it will be released soon, this week hopefully.